# Exclude column from resultset if subquery returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how/if there is a way to exclude a column from the final resultset if the results of a sub-query are null.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like below.

If there is a consultant you'd get as a resultset:

firstName, lastName, department, consultant

If there is NO consultant you'd get as a resultset:

firstName, lastName, department

My query is currently:

```
SELECT
    firstName,
    lastName,
    department,
    (
        SELECT consultantName
        FROM consultants c
        INNER JOIN employees e c.userId = e.userId
    )
FROM employees
ORDER BY department,lastName
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Why not `JOIN` to the table and then just do `WHERE consultantName IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: You need two separate queries, because one version has three columns and the second has four.  A single query cannot return different numbers of columns.

Comment: Jagged or variable columns are not allowed unless you want the results in JSON or XML

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm still fairly new at SQL, what do you mean by two queries. Can you show how what I have would be written as you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of columns will not change depending on the resultset, so you will always have 4 columns.

What you can do is a LEFT JOIN that will fill the Consultant column with NULL when no items are a match

```
SELECT
    e.firstName,
    e.lastName,
    e.department,
    c.consultantName
FROM employees e
LEFT join consultants c
  on e.userId = c.userId
ORDER BY department,lastName
```

In the case you want two different resultset, you can write two queries :
Return 3 columns only for when the consultant doesn't exist

```
    SELECT
        e.firstName,
        e.lastName,
        e.department,
    FROM employees e
    WHERE userId not in 
        (
            select userId from consultants 
        )
    ORDER BY department,lastName
```

Return 4 columns when there is a match

```
SELECT
    e.firstName,
    e.lastName,
    e.department,
    c.consultantName
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN consultants c
  on e.userId = c.userId
ORDER BY department,lastName
```